# How do I change the main icons for the Azure DevOps wiki document

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-wiki

I was wondering how I would go about changing those icons that sit on the left-hand side of the wiki document in the wiki document list inside of ADO. If possible I would like to have an icon for "Folder" (or pages that has sub-pages) and other icons for pages without sub-pages. I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

[image: See the icons]

I have tried looking at Wiki settings but I don't have access to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is No.  I tried to change the icons but no luck.
The wiki is stored in a repository.

[image]

It needs some extension to do it, or I may say Wiki Settings lacks details for changing the settings.

I can say that your requirement is acceptable so raise a new feature request in Official Forum of Azure-DevOps [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues) and on [Feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps) Forum of Azure DevOps.